# Configuring the default drawing color in Firefox' PDF viewer

Tags: firefox, pdf, colors

Firefox allows to view PDF files and even draw on them with either text or a pen for which color, opacity and stroke width can be set.

I have to read and scribble into many PDF files, so it would be great to persist the selected triple of color, opacity and stroke width. A journey into about:config did not turn up anything related.

Is it possible at all to configure the default values for the drawing tool in the Firefox PDF viewer?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no *straightforward* way to configure the initial values of these settings.

It's only possible by unpacking the omni.ja file and editing the relative code (it's javascript).

Comment: Eeek, so I would need a script that patches this up after each update. Let's see if I get annoyed enough to do this. If you write your comment as an answer, I could upvote. :-)